# Javascript can't access property of an object

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object (returned from jQuery ajax) that looks like this:

```
data:{
    materials:{
        1:{
            id:1,
            name:"jacob"
        }//1 (some integer)
    }//materials
}//data
```

I'm trying to access `name`, but I can't get passed the object `1`. I tried using [`makeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) like this

```
var m  = $.makeArray(data.materials);
var m0 = m.shift();
console.log(m);
console.log(m0);
```

`$isArray(m)` & `$.isArray(m0)` return true, but `m` and `m0` both return:

```
1:{
    id:1,
    name:"jacob"
}//1 (some integer)
```

I expect that `shift()` to return the object that's inside of `1`.

When I try to access `m0.name` it returns undefined, and when I try to access `m[1]` it returns undefined.

btw `data.materials["1"].name` works. the problem is `1` is variable (I don't know what it will be, so I wanted to use `shift()` which doesn't work on an object).

**EDIT:** So it seems that there is a limitation within [`makeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/): since an object property is not supposed to be named with a number, that function does not convert the rest of the object and the output is some kind of object-array hybrid (on which you cannot use array functions like `shift()`), so the quick-n-dirty solution I came to was to loop thru it like this:

```
var m = data.materials,
    id;
for ( key in m ) { id = key; }
console.log( m[id].name );
```

It's not all that clean, so if there's a better way, please let me know.

p.s. The `1:{}` is there in the first place because the controller returns multiple "materials" under certain conditions (which will never be true when this js is used).

Comment: What about data.materials["1"]?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `data.materials["1"].name`

http://jsfiddle.net/nq4RE/

Jacob, I see you updated your question.

To use a variable, you simply call `data.materials[your_variable_here].name`

http://jsfiddle.net/nq4RE/1/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try: `data.materials[1].name`?

But in my opinion using number as property name is misleading.